# How to increment jquery ui datepicker programmatically

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, uidatepicker

Basically I want to take date from one field and then increment day and set it to another date field.

This is kind of psuedo-code:

```
var date1 = $( '#date1' ).datepicker( 'getDate' );

var incrementDate = date1 + 1 //increment day

$( '#date2' ).datepicker('setDate', incrementDate );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var date1 = $('#date1').datepicker('getDate');

var date = new Date( Date.parse( date1 ) ); 
date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );

var newDate = date.toDateString(); 
newDate = new Date( Date.parse( newDate ) );

$('#date2').datepicker('setDate', newDate );
```

Comment: what's the point of the second Date.parse to create newDate? would something bad happen if we just passed date to datepicker right after date.setDate?

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = new Date($('#date1').datepicker('getDate'));
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
$('#date1').datepicker('setDate', date);
```